# Capture Workload From Production And Replay On Test Environment

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have a question about taking Workload from Production, the server cannot be shut down, go offline.

I am using WorkloadTools, I have read about Microsoft Utilities, but it seems they are discarded for time being.

I've tried to capture the workload with overlap time to get some window to modificate the source file if needed. It was about 20 seconds, it was not sufficient, because there are hundreds/thousands commands going through the server at given time. I took DB backup and transaction logs to get to the point where the DB would be at the most closest point to the Production. I've done reseeds on Identity columns.

If I may ask, how to capture the workload using WorkloadTools and not shut down the server for quite time? Is there a function using snapshots that would help me? I am out of options that come to my mind.

EDIT:

I did succesful capture and replay when there was no load on it (after running the cmd, there were events coming through). It was from different source though, it was not the production environment. These were my first steps before moving on to the production.

Edit2:

***Setting the DB:***
[image]
[image]

***SQLite DB:***
[image]

***Error from replay (missing record in the table)***:

2022-12-14 11:57:36.0902 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayConsumer : 1301000 events queued for replay ( 28% )
2022-12-14 11:57:36.8018 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayConsumer : 1302000 events queued for replay ( 28% )
2022-12-14 11:57:37.7756 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayConsumer : 1303000 events queued for replay ( 28% )
2022-12-14 11:57:38.6316 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayWorker : Worker [209] - 6000 commands executed.
2022-12-14 11:57:38.6316 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayWorker : Worker [209] - 90000 commands pending.
2022-12-14 11:57:38.6350 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayWorker : Worker [209] - Last Event Sequence: 176656
2022-12-14 11:57:38.6350 - Info - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayWorker : Worker [209] - 205 commands per second.
2022-12-14 11:57:38.8016 - Warn - WorkloadTools.Consumer.Replay.ReplayWorker : Worker [84] - Sequence[383713] - Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_RevenueRecognition_OrderItems". The conflict occurred in database "DB", table "dbo.OrderItems", column 'OrderItem_ID'.
The statement has been terminated.

***Problem:***

There are steps above. I've tried to tinker a bit with point-in-time because I cannot start at flat 10:02:04 as seen in the Source File (SQLite). I do that and reseed of IDs to Max_Value of ID column. Then I start the replay and start getting errors as shown in the image. Because there is just unending flow of queries to Production DB, there may be nuances as: If the query starts a little time before start of capture, it will not be captured and as seen in the image there is a lot going on (The record won´t be in the DB also, if it is running longer than my backups). By this point I may have not some records that are needed in other tables.

So I can make bigger window overlap, like 10 minute, the longest query that I have encountered was running for 2,5 minutes. This solution is not the best option, because there are too many events going on in one second, that I would be unable to say, this can go through, this not. My question is: What do I need to do to resolve this problem and get clean capture? For a record there are around 900 events per second.

Comment: "*If I may ask, how to capture the workload using WorkloadTools and not shut down the server for quite time*' - Why do you think it shuts down the server?

Comment: @J.D. No, I am asking how to capture the workload without shutting down the server. I am unable to get to the state, where I would be able to do replay on test environment without magnitude fo errors. I have some samples from Production but even after the cleaning the DB, where its state would be almost similar to Production DB, isn't enough. I did succesful capture and replay when there was no load on it (after running the cmd, there were events coming through), this capture and replay were not from Production, it was testing before trying the production part..

Comment: Is your question how to restore the database such that it's at the same point the workload capture started? Have you tried point-in-time recovery?

Comment: Without seeing the errors you're getting, I don't think anyone can really offer advise unfortunately. If you're running into replay issues with the schemas being out of sync or some kind of odd data integrity issues, then you'd want to to restore Transaction Log backups up to the point of which you stopped your workload capture.

Comment: @J.D. I've tried to explain it with pictures and text in EDIT2

Answer (score 0):

Typically in replay you tolerate a few errors in the beginning of the trace.  And there's no way to avoid some failures, like `sp_execute` against a cursor defined outside of your trace window.

But if you want to put the test database at the exact lsn you start the trace, you can mark a transaction after starting the trace and restore the database to the log mark you created.  See [Restore the transaction log to a mark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#restoring_transaction_log_to_mark)